# How to programmatically hide a single row from list view (Custom adapter)

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view app and using a custom adapter, but I can't hide a specific row from the adapter.

**My codes**

**-: In java :-**

`Adapter`

```
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    int[] imageArray;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArray;

    public Adapter(Context context, String[] titles1, String [] description1, int[] img1) {
        super(context, R.layout.settings_list_row, R.id.settingsTitles, titles1);
        this.imageArray = img1;
        this.titleArray = titles1;
        this.descriptionArray = description1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_list_row,parent,false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.settingsIcons);
        TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.settingsTitles);
        TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.settingsDescriptions);
        myImage.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
        myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
        myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

`Main activity`

```
String [] titles = {"ti1","ti2","ti3","ti4","ti5"};
    String [] descriptions = {"de1","de2","de3","de4","de5"};
    int [] images = {R.drawable.ic_image,R.drawable.ic_image,R.drawable.ic_image,R.drawable.ic_image,R.drawable.ic_image};
    ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), titles, descriptions, images);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**-: To remove :-**

`adapter.remove(position == 0);`

But not working!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `ListAdapter`, you would simply filter out the items you do not want displayed by returning modified values for `getCount()`, `getItem()` and `getItemId()` as appropriate.

For Example

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;

    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

    holder.tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    if (items[position].NeedForCollapsed){
        System.out.println("set Visibility.Gone");
        holder.tvName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return rowView;
    }

    //new values
    holder.tvName.setText(items[position].name);
    holder.img.setImageResource(GetImageID(items[position]));

    return rowView;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tvName;
    ImageView img;
}
```

Comment: How do I receive the value in the adapter? and it's showing error!